# Docker Java Springboot with MySQL: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker

I have a spring boot application connected to MySQL, and It works very well unless it is dockerized, when It is dockerized it throws an exception:

```
2022-06-16 14:50:22.355 ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - [HikariPool.java:594] - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
app_1      | java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed
```

I tried to change the connection string to be

```
jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/BONANZA?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
```

But nothing happened still resulting in the same exception.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven AS MAVEN_BUILD
COPY ./ /app
WORKDIR /app


RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests

# second stage: use open jdk 11.0.11 image to build the project docker image
FROM openjdk:17-alpine

COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /app/target/Bonanza-Api.jar /usr/local/lib/app.jar

EXPOSE 8585

CMD java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod /usr/local/lib/app.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the POM for correct version of JDBC dependencies like spring data and spring connector, they should be the same.
I had similar issue with mismatched dependency versions.

Comment: The same with what?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).